# How to cross-reference an unnumbered section?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

So, this is pretty well-known:

```
\section{boring Hello World} \label{bHW}
```

but in this case?:

```
\section*{boring Hello World with no section} \label{bHW_noSection}
```

with the above I got referenced to the last section in my document and not to the `\section*` itself.

Hints are welcomed

Comment: How exactly do you want to refer to a section that is nor numbered? Might be best to just refer by page number. In this case I've also used features to cite the title of the unnumbered section and then combined that with the page number.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, just wondering how to do this reference, good tips about title and page number, I'll try it.

Comment: i think you need an explicit anchor.  see [Clicking on a link I don't jump to the **exact** location of the label, just somewhere around it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47508/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a named reference, i.e. to the name of the starred section? This can be done with `\nameref` or `\nameref*` if no link is needed!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}



\section{A section}

In \textbf{\nameref*{abus}} we will see a lot of boring stuff and here's a link to it: \nameref{abus}

\blindtext[10]

\section*{A boring unnumbered section} \label{abus}

Very boring stuff



\end{document}
```