# remove sections numbering

Tags: sectioning

I have the next code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{%
\section[#1]{\centering\normalfont\scshape #1}}
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{%
\subsection[#1]{\bfseries\normalfont\scshape #1}}
\newcommand{\ssubsubsection}[1]{%
\ssubsubsection[#1]{\bfseries\normalfont\scshape #1}}

\begin{document}
\ssection{Special relativity}
  bla bla bla
\ssubsection{Lorentz's transformation}
  bla bla bla
\ssubsection{Minkowski space-time}
  bla bla bla
 \end{document}
```

anyone know how to remove the sections numbering?

And if I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright, 16pt]{article}
```

Why the letters are not bigger?

Comment: with standard class `article` is one you have only `10,11,12pt` you can try with `extarticle` class there is `14pt`, `17pt` and even more. For section numbering use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`

Comment: There is better way to redefine style of sections.

Comment: You have tagged this titlesec which is a package that would allow you to properly declare section formatting but you have not used that package at all and are placing formatting commands in the argument of `\section` which is just wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 47):

Add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to preamble.

[image: PDF no section numbering]

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange. Maybe you could add some information how this differs from the other answers? What are the advantages? Are there disadvantages? Also the same answer was given in a comment by touhami, maybe you can mention that.

Answer (score 37):

- To center the sections, you could for example use the `sectsty` package
- One way to remove the numbers from the sections is to use unnumbered sections denoted by the stars.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

    \section*{Special relativity}
    bla bla bla
    \subsection*{Lorentz's transformation}
    bla bla bla
    \subsection*{Minkowski space-time}
    bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NiklasMertsch `\pageref` and `\nameref` still work for unnumbered sections, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277937/36296

Answer (score 11):

To remove section numbering but keep references to the section you can add this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the numbering from the sections and not from the table of contensts try this :

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```