# Conflict with hyperref and titlesec

Tags: hyperref, titlesec

The cross-reference (`\nameref`) in the code below does not populate unless I remove the `titlesec` package. I need both packages. How can I get around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Section title}\label{first}
See section \nameref{first}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

See [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf) of `hyperref` contains:

> ```
> titlesec
> --------
>   "nameref" supports titlesec, but hyperref does not
>   (unsolved is the anchor setting, missing with unnumbered
>   section, perhaps problems with page breaks with numbered ones).
> ```

Thus, you can use `nameref` with `titlesec`, but `hyperref` is unsupported then.
The example compiles with `nameref` instead of `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Section title}\label{first}
See section \nameref{first}.
\end{document}
```

However, `\nameref{first}` is empty, because the `\label{first}` does not reference a numbered section. Unnumbered sections are not supported.

## Workaround

The following workaround defines a macro `\starsection` that passes its argument to `\section*`. Then an internal command (`\@currentlabelname`) is defined via the internal interface of `nameref` (macro `\NR@gettitle`). Then, `\label` can pick up the current section title for use with `\nameref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \NR@gettitle{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\starsection{Section title}\label{first}
See section \nameref{first}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: titleref is not titlesec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, the README also contains an entry for `titlesec`, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I am not able to get my example to format if I use nameref and titlesec, but not hyperref.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question popped up as I was searching for answers to the same conflict using `titlesec`, `hyperref` and `\section*{}` that needed labelling, I like to share the workaround that Ulrike Fisher published on the forum a few years later. So this question will be crosslinked to that answer and hence be of benefit of all.

Ulrike defined a new command, that can be used to augment the starred section (and others) requiring a label. You can find her answer here: [nameref is not working for unnumbered sections due to titilesec and latexbangla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603292/nameref-is-not-working-for-unnumbered-sections-due-to-titilesec-and-latexbangla) .

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is just keeping your numbered sections, but visually hide them by using a combination of [removing the numbering of sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517837/70734) and the [removing of numbering from toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218699/70734):

```latex
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```

This creates a TOC with nicely aligned links without numbers, linking to nicely aligned section headers without numbers, precisely to where the numbered section would link.