# \nameref not working with starred sections

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, starred-version, nameref

I have an appendix in my document which I want to reference by its name in the text. I use the starred `\section*` command here, because I do not want the appendix to appear in the TOC. However, `\nameref` simply puts an empty space where the word "Appendix" should be.

---

Thanks to the comments, I now can see that the problem is actually the `titlesec` package. I want my section `Appendix` to appear as a non-numbered item in the TOC, but at the same time, I want to do there referencing with `\nameref` as explained above. So I edited my example to now look like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
    \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents  % added this line
    
\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:section_1}

All that can be seen in the \nameref{sec:appendix}.

\section*{Appendix}
\label{sec:appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}    % added this line

Here comes the appendix.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, your example works just fine if `titlesec` and the `\sectionbreak` is removed

Comment: nameref does work with starred section, titlesec is the problem.

Comment: I need `titlesec` to adjust my heading styles. Is there any way how I can do that and still use `\nameref` in the way I want?

Comment: What do you want your heading styles to look like?

Comment: `{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}` with Calibri as the default bold font.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question popped up as I was searching for answers to the same conflict using `titlesec`, `hyperref` and `\section*{}` that needed labelling, I like to share the workaround that Ulrike Fisher published on the forum a few years later. So this question will be crosslinked to that answer and hence be of benefit of all.

Ulrike defined a new command, that can be used to augment the starred section (and others) requiring a label. You can find her answer here: [nameref is not working for unnumbered sections due to titilesec and latexbangla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603292/nameref-is-not-working-for-unnumbered-sections-due-to-titilesec-and-latexbangla) .

The reason why the combination `'titlesec` with `hyperref` / `nameref` doesn't work is explained by Heiko Oberdiek in this question: [Conflict with hyperref and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397031/conflict-with-hyperref-and-titlesec) .