# nameref is not working for unnumbered sections due to titilesec and latexbangla

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, nameref

I am trying to cross-reference the unnumbered chapters and sections in a book. But I found out `\nameref` is not working for unnumbered sections due to the packages `latexbangla` and `\titlesec`.
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

% Kalpurush font: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html 

\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Kalpurush]{latexbangla}        
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}                
   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\raggedright\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\Huge§\,\uccon}\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}    
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}    

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter} \label{chap:1}
\section*{Unnumbered Section} \label{sec:1}
Check \nameref{sec:2} in \nameref{chap:2}.

\chapter{Numbered Chapter} \label{chap:2}
\section{Numbered Section} \label{sec:2}
Check \nameref{sec:1} in \nameref{chap:1}. % Here, \nameref{sec:1} isn't appearing

\end{document}
```

And an error is showing up:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 28.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`titlesec` doesn't support `nameref` (or `nameref` doesn't support `titlesec`). You will have to set the name for the label manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcurrentname[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter}\setcurrentname{Unnumbered Chapter}\label{chap:1}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}\setcurrentname{Unnumbered Section}\label{sec:1}
Check \nameref{sec:2} in \nameref{chap:2}.

\chapter{Numbered Chapter} \label{chap:2}
\section{Numbered Section} \label{sec:2}
Check \nameref{sec:1} in \nameref{chap:1}. % Here, \nameref{sec:1} isn't appearing

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But it's not taking me to the exact place of the referenced section. In that case, should I use `\phantomsection` command?