# Workaround for titlesec/nameref conflict not working for memoir class?

Tags: memoir

There's a nice workaround for the `titlesec`/`nameref` conflict [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603305/272500) but I'm finding it doesn't work for the memoir class. Below is my MWE that works for the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
% \documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcurrentname[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\newcommand{\labelledsection}[2]{\section*{#1}\setcurrentname{#1}\label{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter}\setcurrentname{Unnumbered Chapter}\label{chap:unnumbered}
\labelledsection{Unnumbered Section}{sec:unnumbered}
Check \nameref{sec:numbered}.

\chapter{Numbered Chapter} \label{chap:numbered}
\section{Numbered Section} \label{sec:numbered}
Check \nameref{sec:unnumbered}.

\end{document}
```

The MWE generates text that correctly refs the section:

[image]

But if I switch to the `memoir` class it refs the chapter?:

[image]

Comment: well I wouldn't use titlesec with memoir. memoir has lots of own configuration options, and finding how who is changing what is a rather challenging.