How to show section title in Scientific Reports LaTeX template?
I like to use paper structure in manuscript using \nameref{key-label} command. However, I can not use it for scientific reports template, as \nameref{test} does not show the section title.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title to see here}
\author[1,*]{Author1}
\author[2]{Author2}
\affil[1]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}
\affil[2]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}
\affil[*]{corresponding.author@email.example}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{foo}\label{test} 
Some text. 
\section*{bar} 
Some text. 
Also see section \nameref{test}.
\end{document}


The class file is available in the overleaf website. Are there any was to use \nameref command to show section title?

I find the answer given here is usefull for the question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603292/nameref-is-not-working-for-unnumbered-sections-due-to-titilesec-and-latexbangla
