# How to make section name appear in ToC when using both fancyhdr and titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, fancyhdr, titlesec, nameref

We want the section *Preface* to appear on the TOC, but as can be seen on the following screenshot, the section name does not appear to be visible, although the dotted line is appearing with page number as well.

[image]

We are using the following lines, when we try to make the section appear in the ToC:

```
\input{sections/0_Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{2.2em}\nameref{sec:preface}} % ---- ADDS PREFACE TO THE TOC
```

What may cause this is that we are using both titlesec and fancyhdr together, although they are in conflict with each other. If we remove the titlesec package, the section name suddenly appears in the TOC:

[image]

How do we make the section name appear in the TOC when still using titlesec and fancyhdr? We need fancyhdr for header, footer etc. and titlesec for changing font size of sections.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} % <------ This here 
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{} %<--- changes font size of sections

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %<---- Before that there
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\mytitle} 

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} 

\input{sections/0_Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{2.2em}\nameref{sec:preface}} % ---- ADDS PREFACE TO THE TOC

\cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{} 
\lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\vspace*{-20em}\tableofcontents\numberline{} 

%\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\newpage

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

0_Preface File:

```
\section*{Preface} \label{sec:preface}

\clearpage
```

Comment: Just like in your previous question: remove the `pagestyles` option from `titlesec`: `\usepackage{titlesec}`. This removes the conflict with `fancyhdr` and it brings the `Preface` back to the ToC. The option doesn't serve anything in your document and only makes thing bad. And the other thing is to rename `\thetitle` to something else, e.g. \TheTitle`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thank you for your reply once again! Unfortunately, removing pagestyles from the package so it only says: \usepackage{titlesec} , does not add the preface to the ToC. Also, i am not sure where it says \thetitle in my MWE. Should have been changed to \mytitle

Comment: Does your include file set the label `\label{sec:preface}`? I'll give you a working example in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is included, but just found out that it might be due to that it is says: \section*{Preface} \label{sec:preface} and the * should ensure that there is no number included in the section, but instead it is the reason for not appearing in the ToC

Comment: @PietervanOostrum i updated the question with the preface file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This appears to be a conflict between the packages `hyperref`, `nameref` (loaded by `hyperref`) and `titlesec` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397032/113546). So I used the solution given there to resolve the conflict.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \NR@gettitle{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

and then use `\starsection` instead of `\section*`

- Removed the `pagestyles` option
- Replaced the `\input{sections/0_Preface}` with

```
\chapter*{Preface}
\label{sec:preface}
```

- renamed `\thetitle` to `\TheTitle`.
- removed the redefinitions of the footer fields.
- And, by the way, this problem would have disappeared if you had written `Preface` instead of `\nameref{sec:preface}` in `\addcontentsline`. You can still make it easier by adding the `\addcontentsline` call to the `\starsection` macro and using `#1` there instead of the `\nameref{sec:preface}`. See the second solution below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{} %<--- changes font size of sections

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \NR@gettitle{#1}%
}
\let\TheTitle\@title
\let\TheAuthor\@author
\let\TheDate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\TheTitle} 

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} 

%\input{sections/0_Preface}
\starsection{Preface} 
\label{sec:preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{2.2em}\nameref{sec:preface}} % ---- ADDS PREFACE TO THE TOC

% \cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
% \rfoot{} 
% \lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\vspace*{-20em}\tableofcontents\numberline{} 

%\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\newpage

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

**Version with `\contentsline` added to `\starsection` macro:**

```
\documentclass[11pt, report]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{} %<--- changes font size of sections

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Header}   % Title
\author {Ahmad Ahmadsen} % Author
\date{\today} % Date

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\starsection}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \NR@gettitle{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{2.2em}#1}%
}
\let\TheTitle\@title
\let\TheAuthor\@author
\let\TheDate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\TheTitle} 

\rfoot{\thepage \space} 
\lfoot{University} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} 

%\input{sections/0_Preface}
\starsection{Preface} 
\label{sec:preface}

% \cfoot{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}
% \rfoot{} 
% \lfoot{} 

\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\vspace*{-20em}\tableofcontents\numberline{} 

%\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


% Add sections here!
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Research Question}

\newpage

\section{Analysis}
\subsection{analys 1}
\subsection{analys 2}
\subsection{analys 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: although one last thing is bugging, and that is the \rfoot{\thepage \space}  and \lfoot{University}. After changing preface from section to chapter, it appeared on the ToC, but removed the rfoot and lfoot , and instead added the roman number to the center , how do i fix this?

Comment: See updated solution nr. 2

Comment: You have also definitions of `\lfoot`, `\cfoot` and `\rfoot` later in the document. These override the earlier ones.