# Reference unnumbered starred header and titlesec

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, starred-version

This is a follow up to this question: [How to cross-reference an unnumbered section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277927/how-to-cross-reference-an-unnumbered-section)

My issue is that, in my document, I use the `{titlesec}` package. For some reason that package interferes with the code found in the example above. As a result, I'm not getting the name of the referenced starred section, just its page number.

How may I get the name of the starred section **and** its page number?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

In \textbf{\nameref*{abus}} we will see a lot of boring stuff and here's a link to it: see \nameref{abus}, \pageref{abus}.

%\blindtext[10]

\section*{A boring unnumbered section} \label{abus}

Very boring stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: This should solve your problem: [nameref breaks for star versions of section/paragraph when titlesec is loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123667/90202)

Comment: Works. Thank you.